# Upload files to oracle cloud storage using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking in docs and `Oracle sdk` to see if there's anything we can upload to oracle storage.

But i didn't found any `php sdk` from `Oracle` or am i missing something?

I have researched a lot, please help me. I want to use `php sdk` to upload the files and folder to `Oracle cloud` and serve those file urls to my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone looking for the solution for the same so i have figured it out and posting the answer here.
After looking at too many online references i got to know Oracle is compatible with Amazon s3 SDK. So all you need is to use AWS sdk and get the access key and secret from Oracle and you are done. Posting some code.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

define('ORACLE_ACCESS_KEY', '***************************************');
define('ORACLE_SECRET_KEY', '***************************************');
define('ORACLE_REGION', '***************************************');
define('ORACLE_NAMESPACE', '***************************************');


function get_oracle_client($endpoint)
{
    $endpoint = "https://".ORACLE_NAMESPACE.".compat.objectstorage.".ORACLE_REGION.".oraclecloud.com/{$endpoint}";

    return new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => ORACLE_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret' => ORACLE_SECRET_KEY,
        ],
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => ORACLE_REGION,
        'bucket_endpoint' => true,
        'endpoint' => $endpoint
    ));
}

function upload_file_oracle($bucket_name, $folder_name = '', $file_name)
{
    if (empty(trim($bucket_name))) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please provide valid bucket name!');
    }

    if (empty(trim($file_name))) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please provide valid file name!');
    }

    if ($folder_name !== '') {
        $keyname = $folder_name . '/' . $file_name;
        $endpoint =  "{$bucket_name}/";
    } else {
        $keyname = $file_name;
        $endpoint =  "{$bucket_name}/{$keyname}";
    }

   
    $s3 = get_oracle_client($endpoint);
    $s3->getEndpoint();
    
    $file_url = "https://objectstorage.".ORACLE_REGION.".oraclecloud.com/n/".ORACLE_NAMESPACE."/b/{$bucket_name}/o/{$keyname}";
    try {
        $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'Key' => $keyname,
            'SourceFile' => $file_name,
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
        ));

        return array('success' => true, 'message' => $file_url);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
    }
}

function upload_folder_oracle($bucket_name, $folder_name)
{
    if (empty(trim($bucket_name))) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please provide valid bucket name!');
    }

    if (empty(trim($folder_name))) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please provide valid folder name!');
    }

    $keyname = $folder_name;
    $endpoint =  "{$bucket_name}/{$keyname}";
    $s3 = get_oracle_client($endpoint);

    try {
        $manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($s3, $keyname, 's3://' . $bucket_name . '/' . $keyname);
        $manager->transfer();
        return array('success' => true);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return array('success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The above code is working and tested for more details please visit link - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm